# How to make zeros for next n-1 elements of n similar elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, xor

I have an integer 667778 and I need to output it as 607008.

I used an array 6,6,7,7,7,8 and xor next similar elements.
I need to this in constant time.

suppose

```
int arr[]={6,6,7,7,7,8}
    int ele=arr[0];
    for (int i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
         if(arr[i]==ele)
            arr[i]=0;
         else
            ele=arr[i];
    }
```

output array arr has `[6,0,7,0,0,8]`
It is taking `O(n)`  n is size of the array
How can i do this in constant time?

Comment: how do you think is possible to do it in less than linear time? you need at least O(n) time to scan through the input array

Comment: Do you have other examples? How does your input look like in general? if you want it in constant time you can't use arrays, so you have to find an algorithm that treats the number at once (regardless it's size)

Comment: @GameDroids f(x) such that f(388,822,442)=3*10^8+8*10^7+2*10^4+4*10^2+2*10^0 and this finally gives output as 380020402

Comment: @GameDroids Actually my x range is 1<= x <=10^100000  and i am thinking to use bigIntegers , whether bigInteger can hold that much big value. I am actually using another for loop  outside this so i want to decrease time complexity of this for loop to O(1)

Comment: Please suggest any other data structure or algorithm

Comment: I don't think you can decrease the complexity of a loop to O(1) - unless you iterate only once. Sorry, my math isn't good enough to help you with your algorithm, though your formula looks pretty good.

Comment: Atleast logn times

Answer (score 0):

Unless the number given will always be 6 digits (in which case you can hard code it, which is technically constant time, but will give equal performance to the loop), then you can't get constant time because the basis of the problem requires looping through the array in the first place.

Is there are reason you want it to work in constant time anyways, as O(n) is the fastest a program can read the data anyways.

Edit:
After reading your comments, I think you need to come up with a different approach so calculating the XORs won't be inside the loop. I can't provide much more help without the original problem.

Comment: Can I do it using regular expression. If yes please provide the code as I am new to it

Comment: @antony regular expressions can some pretty amazing things, but they can’t perform math operations to my knowledge. If you edit your post and include the original problem I could try to help some more

Comment: @ BeyondPerception see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430181/how-can-i-decrease-the-time-complexity-for-this-question?noredirect=1#comment101362750_57430181