# How can I decrease the time complexity for this question?

Tags: java, loops, biginteger

I am solving a problem such that for every given number between range (inclusive of boundary integers), I calculate the sum of the modified value of those numbers. For example,

```
x = 388,822,442
f(388,822,442)=3800200402
```

i.e; makes zeros for the identical digits. f(x) is modified value.

I iterated through each digit of an integer and made it zero if repeated.

```
 BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s[], s1[];
        s = bf.readLine().trim().split("\\s+");
        s1 = bf.readLine().trim().split("\\s+");
        BigInteger sb = new BigInteger(s[1]);
        BigInteger sb1 = new BigInteger(s1[1]);
        BigInteger indexIncre = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger first = new BigInteger(s[1]);
        BigInteger last = new BigInteger(s1[1]);
        BigInteger length = last.subtract(first);
        BigInteger summation = new BigInteger("0");
         for (index = new BigInteger("0"); !index.subtract(length).toString().equals("1"); 
           index =index.add(indexIncre)) 
          {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(first.toString());
            int len = str.length();
            char c = str.charAt(0);


 for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) 
     {
            if (str.charAt(i) == c) {
                str.setCharAt(i, '0');
            } else
                c = str.charAt(i);
        }
            first = first.add(indexIncre);
            summation = summation.add(new BigInteger(str.toString()));

        }
        BigInteger modulo = BigInteger.valueOf((long) Math.pow(10, 9) + 7);
        System.out.println(summation.mod(modulo));
```

For example 
**Input**

```
1 8
2 12
```

**output**

```
49
```

This is in the form of

**Input**
  NL L 
  NR R

The range of NL,L,NR,R are

1≤NL,NR≤10^5 
 1≤L≤R<10^100,000

Modified value is `f(x)`

```
f(8)=8,f(9)=9,f(10)=10,f(11)=10,f(12)=12
```

and modulo the sum of all these `f(x) by 10^9+7`

Comment: What do NL,L, NR, R stand for?

Comment: NL is length of left most string and L is the string ,NR is the length of right most string and R is right most string. For example in the question length of number string  8 is 1 and length of number string 12 is 2 . The total number strings are 8,9,10,11,12

Comment: @WJS Can we reduce the time complexity by using dynamic programming

Comment: I don't know for certain.  Regular expressions can be very expensive.  Can you provide an example that is taking a long time for you to compute?

Comment: number string that is less than 10^18

Comment: regular expression doesn't solve the problem in an efficient way, so i am thinking of other algorithm that reduces time complexity form O(n^2) to atleast O(nlogn)