# How to replace consecutive repeated characters in a string by '0' using regex?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a `String s="666788899"`

and i need to output it as `600780090`

Is there any regex in java that i can use to change the string like this.

I solved this using naive approach. Actually i am solving a problem that includes another loop with array of strings like this. Including my inner loop it goes up to O(n^2) which is not acceptable.

```
 int len=str.length();
 char c=str.charAt(0);
 for(int i=1;i<len;i++)
 {   
     if(str.charAt(i)==c)
     {
         str.setCharAt(i,'0');
     }     
     else
         c=str.charAt(i);
 }
```

Input String:

```
3888667222
```

Output String:

```
3800607200
```

Comment: You cannot count an arbritrary amount within a regex (because you cannot count with an arbritrary amount with a DFA). Thus, you cannot solve your problem with regex.

Comment: @Turing85 True for a pure regex, not true if using a regex API which supports callbacks (and Java basically does support them).

Comment: This must be a homework assignment because I saw another post yesterday (since removed)  asking the same thing.  The requirement was to sum up all numbers from 1 to n inclusive and convert any numbers as required above when they had duplicates.

Comment: @WJS I agree, and I have seen a number of DP questions here today.  Maybe they are all from the same class.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a mere

```
.replaceAll("(?<=(.))\\1", "0")
```

Or, if you need to allow matching line break characters,

```
.replaceAll("(?s)(?<=(.))\\1", "0")
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kkwf9U/1) and the [Java demo online](http://ideone.com/jzEZdO):

```
System.out.println("666788899".replaceAll("(?<=(.))\\1", "0")); // => 600780090
System.out.println("3888667222".replaceAll("(?<=(.))\\1", "0")); // => 3800607200
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - `Pattern.DOTALL` inline embedded flag
- `(?<=(.))` - a positive lookbehind that contains a capturing group that matches into Group 1 any char
- `\1` - an inline backreference that matches and *consumes* the next char that is the same as the previous one.

So, the first char is kept all the time while the consequent ones are replaced with a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a formal Java regex pattern matcher, for a regex option:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("666788899");
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while(matcher.find()) {
    String zeroes = matcher.group(0).substring(1).replaceAll(".", "0");
    matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, matcher.group(1) + zeroes);
  }
matcher.appendTail(buffer);
System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

This prints:

```
600780090
```

The general pattern I am following here is to use a regex *callback* function.  We want to match any single digit/character which is followed by that same thing one or more times.  Then, inside the callback we figure out how many zeroes we need to replace with, after the original initial character.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not decreasing time complexity, yet increasing time. Is there a better approach than this to decrease time complexity. I mean can we do it using dynamic programming. If yes would you please explain it.

Comment: Yes, we could try dynamic programming, but that's not what your original question asked for.

Comment: Would you please answer the dp solution for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430181/how-can-i-decrease-the-time-complexity-for-this-question

Comment: Well, for numbers that size, I guess you would need a string solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the remainder and division operators to accomplish this.  But you are limited to numbers that fall into that range.

```java
   // convert consecutive, duplicate, digits to 0.
   public static long convert(long k) {
      long n = k % 10;
      long sum = 0;
      if (k > 0) {
         sum = convert(k / 10);
      }
      if (k % 10 == (k / 10) % 10) {
         n = 0;
      }
      sum = sum * 10 + n;
      return sum;
   }
```

Here is an example.

```java
      long val = 282288829229991333L;
      System.out.println(val);
      System.out.println(convert(val));
```

Prints

282288829229991333

282080029209001300

Here is a method that just uses a character array but it doesn't use regex.  And it is comparatively very efficient.

```java
   public static String convert(String a) {
      char[] chars = a.toCharArray();
      char c = chars[0];
      int i = 1;
      while (i < chars.length) {
         char cc = chars[i];
         if (c == cc) {
            chars[i] = '0';
         }
         else {
            c = cc;
         }
         i++;
      }
      return String.valueOf(chars);
   }
```

Comment: OP doesn’t say all expected Strings are numeric, and even if they were that they do not exceed 19 digits, and it’s hard to justify the quantity of code required by your approach when it can be done in [one simple line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445281)

Comment: Well, my method (the second one) is about 20 times faster than the one you cited. The OP also is using `BigInteger` and may be thrown very large numbers. (I checked out the other post). And the main point was to find an efficient method. So the justification was in the requirement stated by the OP.  And here's the requirement as stated [online](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/288/E)